# In RBFS, why should expanded nodes inherit F-value of their parent, if their f-value (g(n)+h(n)) is less than their parent's F-value

Tags: search-algorithms

Here https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/RBFS and here https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2013-14/F/3401/slides/15b-RBFS.pdf it's said that

> f[s] ← max(g(s)+h(s) , f[node] )

Why is it so? I can see a point in it, in a way that F-value is responsible for telling us what is the best accessible way along the path, and if the best accessible value from the parent's node is x, then obviously it's not less than x in its child as well. But I can't see why the algorithm couldn't do without this inheritance. Moreover, suppose I expand node (that has been previously expanded) with F-value of 10. Its 2 children have g(n) + h(n) 9 and 8. I would like to go down the node with 8, because its value is better and it has a better chance, however they both now inherit 10 and are the same, so I could go down the node with 9 as well.

Comment: what would be the correct assignment according to you? Remember that to go to a child one has to pass through the parent node

Comment: @NikosM.
assign g(n) + h(n), even if it's less than parent's F-value. I don't see any problem with it, as it doesn't break the bound.

Comment: f-value has to be strictly non-decreasing from parent to child, else algorithm (like A* algorithm) cannot apply heuristics correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found a great paper where it's explained in details. They actually present a version of RBFS, Simple RBFS (SRBFS). where children nodes don't inherit parent's F-value, explain why it's inefficient (a lot of redundant work that already took place), and also explain in which cases inheritance should take place and in which - shouldn't.
https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1992/AAAI92-082.pdf